# MySQL: SELECT from 2 tables, keeping the records of the second table when primary key matches

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with the same structure but different content:

```
table_a:
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2023-02-02 |
|  2 | 2023-10-12 |
|  3 | 2023-02-04 |
+----+------------+

table_b:
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  3 | 2022-11-11 |
+----+------------+
```

I'm trying to make a query that selects records from both tables, and on duplicate key (in this case 3), select the `table_b` one.

So the result would be:

```
query:
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2023-02-02 |
|  2 | 2023-10-12 |
|  3 | 2022-11-11 |
+----+------------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT * from table_a a left join table_b b on a.id = b.id;
+----+------------+------+------------+
| id | date       | id   | date       |
+----+------------+------+------------+
|  1 | 2023-02-02 | NULL | NULL       |
|  2 | 2023-10-12 | NULL | NULL       |
|  3 | 2023-02-04 |    3 | 2023-11-11 |
+----+------------+------+------------+
```

Is there a way to overwrite the `table_a` record with the `table_b` one to get everything in 2 columns instead of 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply applying `UNION` between all records from `table_a` that do not have a matching id in `table_b`. Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_b)

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table_b
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zraxe5fr)***